# Using object accessors in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I was looking at a javascript code here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp

Where they have shown using object accessors in javascript.

Being a superset of JS, I tried to use it in AS3 but I am getting compiler error

```
var p = {

  get a() {
    return 1;
  }

};

trace(p.a);
```

I hope there must be some way to use it in AS3? Any ideas?

I already know about the longer syntax though which of course works:

```
var p = {

  a:function() {
    return 1;
  }



};

trace(p.a());
```

Answer (score 0):

AS3 syntax is very different from JavaScript. Variables have type (even if it's just `Object`). The [AS3 reference](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) shows an example of creating a dynamic object, which is really more of an associative array:

```
var obj:Object = {a:"foo", b:"bar"};
```

While AS3 does allow for some of the idiosyncracies of JavaScript, I strongly suggest that you treat it like a proper strongly-types programming language (more like C# or Java, than JavaScript) because this leads to cleaner code and better performance (in some cases).

If you know the properties of the object at design time, you should create classes with get/set properties and methods, because these will have much better performance than a dynamic object.

Adding dynamic functions to objects relies on using the [`Function`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html) type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are getters and setters in AS3, but they are available in classes only.

Implementation:

```
package
{
    public class ExampleGS
    {
        public function get a():int
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var p:* = new ExampleGS;

trace(p.a); // 1
```

More info about [getters and setters](https://riptutorial.com/actionscript-3/example/21402/getter-and-setter).